# Is there a way of shuffling partition data on Apache Ignite?

Tags: ignite

I've got a question that is related to data repartitioning.
Suppose there's a cache with a pre-defined affinity key. Assume I need to repartition data with a new affinity key. I'm wondering whether there is a way of shuffling partition data across all nodes by a new affinity key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repopulate the data in that case.

- First, it's a static configuration and can't be changed on the fly.
- The second, most likely you will need to clear meta-information for that particular type, i.e. clean `work/binary_meta` folder.
- The last one - once you changed it, you won't be able to locate the data since most likely it will be stored in a different partition.

In other words, say, you had a cache key with two fields A and B: K(A,B) where A is your affinity key. Say, your `Key(1,2)` was mapped to a partition `5`. In that case, to locate the value, Ignite will search for this partition 5 depending on which node hold the primary copy of it. Later you wanted to have B as the affinity key and re-configure the cache accordingly. In that case, `Key(1,2)` might now be mapped to a partition `780`, meaning that Ignite will never search for a partition `5` and won't be able to locate the previous data.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Am I right that there's a single way to do so is to create a new cache with a new affinity key?

Comment: Yes, alternatively you might adjust the current cache, just make sure there is no data inside. If persistence is enabled, then it's better to remove the data explicitly, if it's im-mem - the data will be gone after a restart.

Comment: @АрсенийНевский I updated the answer, hope it makes the process cleaner.